# PHPass not working when checking password

Tags: php, bcrypt, phpass

I'm trying to use PHPass with a new site. I generated a hash like this and stored it in the database:

```
$hasher = new \Hautelook\Phpass\PasswordHash(8, true);
$password = $hasher->HashPassword('secretpassword');
// I store $password in the DB for the user
```

On the login page, I get the user and use CheckPassword to see if they are the same:

```
function authUser($username, $password, $hasher, $db) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue("username", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->fetch();

    $check = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $user['password']);
    if($check) {
        return $user;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`$user['password']` does contain the correct hash that I stored, so I know that is correct. `$password` is the plaintext password passed in from the form. `CheckPassword()` always returns false, but from all the tutorials I've perused this morning this looks correct and should work. `$hasher` is created the same way, with 8 for a cost and portable set to true.

I can't figure out why CheckPassword always returns false. Do I need to initialize the hasher for the CheckPassword differently than when I hashed it? Am I missing something simple?

I'm running PHP 5.3.19 on CentOS 6.3, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without going through the database? Just hash → check directly?

Comment: Are you 2000% sure the value the database returns is identical...?

Comment: Sorry to take so long coming back to this. Yes, I did check that. Eventually it started working, and now fails again. I've even tried rehashing and resetting the password but now I'm stuck in a loop where the DB version fails, but hashing and immediately checking works.

Answer (score 1):

check the password size in database if it is <50 then it maybe has problems storing the complete hash, that's why is allways false